# Putting a variable in quotations in R (Escaping quotations for a functions)

Tags: r

I’m trying to make a function that runs bash/zsh commands from within R.

I want the variable ‘command’ to get pumped into the function.

```
bash <- function(command){
system('bash -c command’)
}
```

or

```
zsh <- function(command){
system(‘zsh -c command’)
}
```

so that I can simply type:

```
bash(ls)
```

or
    zsh(cd)
(yes, i know R has `setwd()` and `list.files` ... just using those an examples. I’m more interested in doing complex commands like `bash(open -a Microsoft\ Excel training data.csv)`

and have it list items from my current directory

But I’m not sure how to escape the quotations.

Comment: You can insert character objects into another with `sprintf("bash -c %s","ls")`.

Comment: Yes, but i want it to be     `bash(insertcommandhere)` So I tried    `bash <- function(bashcommand){system(sprintf("bash -c %s",bashcommand))}` but it didn’t work. Sorry, I’m new to the `sprintf` function

Comment: You can use `paste` to join strings, and `shQuote` to quote them so they work in your shell.

Comment: You can convert the bare symbol to a character with `as.character(substitute(bashcommand))`, but if you want anything even remotely more complicated you're probably better off passing arguments as strings.

Comment: Specifically, the more complex commands you say you're interested in will *only* work if you pass them as a character; otherwise it's not even a valid single R expression. So you'd **have** to do `bash("open -a Microsoft\ Excel training data.csv")`, for example.